# Network file transfer not going through

Tags: linux, scp, file-transfer

Trying to transfer a file from my raspberryPi to my laptop (in the same network) via the terminal, but it takes a while and then says

`ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.121 port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection`

The command in the terminal reads:

```
$ scp examplefile.txt bruno@192.168.1.121:C:\Users\bruno\Documents
```

When I enter `$ ping 192.168.1.121` I get `PING 192.168.1.121 (192.168.1.121) 56(84) bytes of data.` and the transfer in the other direction:

```
scp C:\Users\Documents\examplefile.txt openhabian@openhabianpi:home
```

works fine. Whats the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your laptop is running Windows 10. For the command you mentioned not working, you need to setup an SSH server on the laptop.

Point is, `scp` relies on remote SSH server to copy files to and from the remote host. As in your case, I'm assuming the Raspberry Pi has an SSH server running on it, so you can always copy files to and from it with `scp` on another machine.